# Код на python не всегда работает верно

Tags: python, алгоритм

я написала код по задаче:

```
Дан массив a длины n, вы можете сделать не более k 
операций следующего типа: выбрать 2
различных элемента в массиве, прибавить 1
к первому и вычесть 1 из второго. 
После применения операции все элемента a
должны остаться неотрицательными.
Какой лексикографически минимальный массив можно 
получить? Массив xлексикографически меньше чем 
массив y, если есть индекс i такой, что 
xi<yi, и xj=yjдля всех 1≤j<i. Проще говоря, 
для первого такого i, где массивы различны, xi<yi.

Входные данные
В первой строке записано одно целое число 
t (1≤t≤20) – количество наборов входных данных.

В первой строке каждого набора входных 
данных записаны 2целых числа n и k
(2≤n≤100, 1≤k≤10000) — размер массива 
и максимальное количество операций.

Во второй строке каждого набора входных 
данных записаны n целых чисел a1, a2, …, an
(0≤ai≤100) — элементы массива a.

Выходные данные
На каждый набор входных данных выведите 
лексикографически минимальный массив, который 
может получиться из исходного за не более чем k
операций.

Пример
входные данные
2
3 1
3 1 4
2 10
1 0
выходные данные
2 1 5 
0 1
```

Но на некоторых тестах он выдает неверный ответ, мой код:

```
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    a, b=map(int, input().split()) 
    s=list(map(int, input().split())) 
    if s.count(0)==a-1:
        print("0 "*(a-1), end="")
        print(max(s))
    else:   
        x=0
        y=a-1
        while s[x]>0 and s[y]>0 and b>0 and s.count(0)<a-1:
            s[x]-=1 
            s[y]+=1 
            b-=1 
            if s[x]==0:
                x+=1 
            if s[y]==0:
                y-=1 
        print(*s)
```

Не знаю что делать, помогите пожалуйста доработать и улучшить код!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Главная идея в вашем коде правильная: брать единички как можно левее и перемещать их как можно правее. Но есть ошибки:

1. Тест с массивом `1 1 0` оставляет его без изменений. Хотя есть меньший ответ - `0 0 2`. Причина в условии `s[y]>0`. Оно лишнее и только мешает. Если последний элемент массива ноль, почему мы отказываемся помещать туда единички? Убираем условие.
2. Тест с массивом `0 1 0 1` оставляет его без изменений. Хотя меньший ответ - `0 0 0 2`. Причина в условии `s[x]>0`. Прерывать цикл из-за нуля в текущей позиции неправильно. Справа от нуля могут быть числа, которые ещё можно обработать. Но ноль в `s[x]` как-то обрабатывать нужно. Поставим условие внутри цикла:

```
        while b>0 and s.count(0)<a-1:
            if s[x] == 0:
                x += 1 
            else:
                s[x]-=1 
                s[y]+=1 
                b-=1 
                if s[x]==0:
                    x+=1 
                if s[y]==0:
                    y-=1
```

3. Условие `if s[y]==0:` никогда не выполняется. `s[y]` или уже был больше нуля или только что получил дополнительную единицу. Убираем его.
4. Условие `if s[x]==0:` было полезным и осталось полезным. Но аналогичное условие уже есть в начале тела цикла. Убираем его:

```
        x=0
        y=a-1
        while b>0 and s.count(0)<a-1:
            if s[x] == 0:
                x += 1 
            else:
                s[x]-=1 
                s[y]+=1 
                b-=1
```

5. Условие `s.count(0)<a-1` полезное, но его можно заменить более простым условием - `x < y`. Пока `x` меньше `y` можно продолжать попытки переносить единицы, иначе цикл надо останавливать. Ещё одна причина - новое условие считается быстрее.
6. Что делает `if s.count(0)==a-1:` в начале программы? Он оптимизирует ситуацию когда в массиве почти все нули. Нужно ли оно? Нет, без него можно обойтись. Программа станет медленнее (но только в специальном случае) и проще. Удаляем:

```
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    a, b=map(int, input().split()) 
    s=list(map(int, input().split())) 
    x=0
    y=a-1
    while b>0 and x < y:
        if s[x] == 0:
            x += 1 
        else:
            s[x]-=1 
            s[y]+=1 
            b-=1 
    print(*s)
```

Последняя версия стала работать правильно. Она ещё и проще. Но это не повод останавливаться.

7. Почему мы переносим единички по одной? Можно перенести сразу `min(s[x], b)` единичек. Окажется что условие внутри цикла не нужно:

```
    while b>0 and x < y:
        m = min(s[x], b)
        s[x] -= m
        s[y] += m
        b -= m
        x += 1
```

8. Условие `b>0` стало не нужно. Оно делает программу немного быстрее, но усложняет. Если его удалить, цикл `while` можно заменить на `for ... range`:

```
n=int(input()) 
for i in range(n):
    a, b=map(int, input().split()) 
    s=list(map(int, input().split())) 
    y=a-1
    for x in range(y):
        m = min(s[x], b)
        s[x] -= m
        s[y] += m
        b -= m
    print(*s)
```

9. Текст лучше отформатировать, переменные привести к терминам из задачи:

```
t = int(input()) 
for _ in range(t):
    n, k = map(int, input().split()) 
    x = list(map(int, input().split())) 
    for i in range(n - 1):
        m = min(x[i], k)
        x[i] -= m
        x[n - 1] += m
        k -= m
    print(*x)
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. Вам необходимо внести изменения в код, чтобы он соответствовал формату ввода и вывода, описанному в задаче. Для этого вам нужно изменить строку "n=int(input())" на "t=int(input())" для чтения количества наборов входных данных. Затем вы должны внести изменения в вывод результата.**

**2. У вас в цикле while условия проверяются в неправильном порядке. Сначала вы должны проверить, есть ли нулевые элементы в массиве, а затем уменьшать b.**

**3. Ваш код не удовлетворяет условию задачи, когда s.count(0) равняется a-1. В этом случае вы должны выводить весь массив равным 0.**

Ниже приведен исправленный код с учетом описанных изменений:

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    s = list(map(int, input().split()))

    if s.count(0) == n - 1:
        result = [0] * n
        result[n - 1] = max(s)
        print(*result)
    else:
        x = 0
        y = n - 1
        while b > 0 and s.count(0) < n - 1:
            if s[x] > 0 and s[y] > 0:
                s[x] -= 1
                s[y] += 1
                b -= 1
            if s[x] == 0:
                x += 1
            if s[y] == 0:
                y -= 1
        print(*s)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`.

Comment: `1 1 0` -> `0 2 0`. Правильный ответ `0 0 2`.